# sending email in android application

Tags: android, email

I just want to send email in android application, I had tried

below is my code:

```
btnfeedbacksubmit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent Email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                Email.setType("text/email");
                Email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] { "abc@gmail.com" });
                Email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Feedback");
                Email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Hi");
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(Email, "Sending Feedback:"));

            }
        });
```

But it shows me an error "No apps can perform this"

What more should I have to do???

Comment: clear your question first?

Comment: i want to insert my sender email andress and paswword for send email and also give the receiver id.. so that client should just type message and send no need to enter any email address to send mail...

Comment: did u got my question?

Comment: No what u want? did not get it.

Comment: @MD see my edited question. I just want to send mail from my application, is there any requirement of sending email id and password?

Comment: do you want to send email programmatically..?

Comment: did u added `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` into u r manifest.xml?

Comment: @MD yes i have added that permission in android coz I have given the link of facebook and its works very well....

Comment: please set the type as `setType("application/octet-stream")` instead of `text/email` and also add your Account into Default Email app

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
email .setType("message/rfc822");
email .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL  , "anemailaddress"});                   
email .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject");
email .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT   , "sometext");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email , "Sending e-mail..."));
```

Also check if you have an e-mailclient installed with a default account.

Comment: Do you have an e-mailaccount installed with a default account?

Comment: that's your problem then, you have to have an e-mailaccount installed, otherwise none is found and you get an error.

Comment: So you want to say that I have to make an account in my pc or have to install email account ?

Comment: There has to be an e-mail client with an account on the android device on which the app is running.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.fromParts(
        "mailto","abc@gmail.com", null));
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "EXTRA_SUBJECT");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send email..."));
```